# WebElement null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Buenas a tod@s. Estoy creando un mini proyecto de appium. A la hora de llamar al webElement en el PO, me está devolviendo null, pero si me hace caso el driver porque me está navegando, creo que es algo que me falta. Os paso el código.
Podemos ver que en el sout cuando llamo al element cookies, me llega null

```
 public class InicioPageObject extends BaseContext  {
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='jss27']")
    public WebElement cookies2;


    public void addData() {
        try {
            driver.navigate().to("http://page.com");
            Thread.sleep(6000); 
            System.out.println("erro1r "+cookies2);
            //WebElement logUserId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='jss27']"));  
            cookies2.click();
            //waitForElementPresent(driver, buttonCookies);
    
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Este es donde se inicia el test:

```
@Test(groups = {"calculadora","open"})// we add the tags that we want to add it
public class InicioTest extends BaseContext{
    
    InicioPageObject home = new InicioPageObject();
    
    
    @Test
    public void openCalculator() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("que es "+driverMobile);
        //driverMobile.navigate().to("http://innocv.com");
        home.addData();
    }
```

y aquí donde inicio si es android o ios.

```
public class BaseContext extends MobileConfiguration implements TestSetup{

     protected AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driverMobile;
        
        @Override
        @BeforeMethod
        public void setUp() throws Exception {  


            String deviceType = System.getProperty("platform");
            System.out.println("Valor de device.type: " + deviceType);
            if (deviceType != null && deviceType.equals("android")) {
                driverMobile = connectAppiumAndroid();
             } else if (deviceType != null && deviceType.equals("ios")) {
                 driverMobile = connectAppiumIos();
             } else {
                 throw new Exception("Plataforma no compatible");
             }}
    @Override
        @AfterMethod
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            if (driverMobile != null) {
                //driverMobile.quit();
            }}
```

Comment: Solo un tip rápido: puedes evitar los `deviceType != null` en tus comprobaciones simplemente *invirtiendo* el equals: `"android".equals(deviceType)`, puesto que en vez de un NullPointerException, simplemente devolverá false porque `"android"` no es igual a `null`.

Comment: En lugar de poner el hilo a dormir, es conveniente usar una [estrategia de espera](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/).